# Unable to fullscreen video on second monitor

Tags: display, videos

I can't run any fullscreen video on my second monitor. I tried with youtube on google chrome, netflix on firefox and vlc.

Any ideas on why?

Answer (score 2):

The same happen to me since Juno, with Loki I could without issue. Now is not possible to upscale any video content

The only way to bypass it is to maximize it/go fullscreen on the main display and then send it to the desired one (<kbd>WINKEY</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT_ARROW</kbd>)

I couldn't figure out where to watch in the logs to check what happen

--

I use chrome to watch netflix and youtube in kiosk mode

just save the app shortcut then edit it and add **--kiosk** and **--window-position=X,0**

where **X** stand for the x coordinate where the second display starts

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

check your displays with:

**$ xrandr --query**

that will make chrome go fullscreen and load on the second display
for youtube -> youtube.com/tv (works awesome)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try to fullscreen on the primary monitor and send it to the second one :D