# Issues with Chrome video playback and Wingpanel after updating to Juno

Tags: release-juno, wingpanel, google-chrome

I just updated to Juno today and everything is running great apart from 2 separate issues.

1. When I watch videos on Google chrome eg. Youtube or Twitch *the video often pauses while the sound continues before starting again when I change from full-screen.*
2. I have found that with any theme that is not the default `wingpanel` will not turn black when windows are maximized. I tried the instructions at the below link but the problem wasn't resolved.

Neither of these issues were present for me in Loki.

Thanks in advance for any help you guys are awesome!

https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/52pmxp/fixing_transparent_wingpanel_with_custom_themes/?ref=share&ref_source=link

Comment: Is this what happen to you with fullscreen and videos? https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/16526/14940

Answer (score 0):

Disable H/W Acceleration in chrome settings for a workaround to video freezing in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

## First question

> When I watch videos on Google chrome eg. Youtube or Twitch the video
>   often pauses while the sound continues before starting again when I
>   change from full-screen

Sometimes you will have to deactivate **H/W Acceleration** on your browser.

For Google chrome you can check if enable or disable with this link

[chrome://gpu/](http://chrome://gpu/)

in the first section you will find a result like this, which may be different

[image]

After

1. got to [chrome://settings/](http://chrome://settings/)
2. At the bottom of the page go to advanced
3. In the system section disable the option
4. relaunch the browser

[image]

In one of my jobs, for our application we had to deactivate this function, because it had problem with the fluidity in our application

## Second question

> I have found that with any theme that is not the default wingpanel
>   will not turn black when windows are maximized. I tried the
>   instructions at the below link but the problem wasn't resolved.

The themes (if I'm not mistaken) are written in CSS, some elementary OS parameters may not take over the CSS of the theme. For example, currently I have a theme which does not make the bar completely transparent when I do not maximize a window.

So I think the theme chooses takes control of the elementary OS setting