# Going fullscreen with a browser locks up that window only on secondary display

Tags: release-juno

I'm relatively new to elementary so sorry if it's been asked before.

I'm running a setup with 2 monitors attached to a GTX 1070, when I go full screen in any browser (Using chrome but did test with Epiphany) on anything but my primary monitor will cause the window to glitch out and render slowly...

Tried disabling hardware acceleration and tried multiple drivers and still having the issue...

Comment: Duplicate https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16526/unable-to-fullscreen-video-on-second-monitor

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not an answer, but I thought I would mention that I've got the same issue in Chrome on Juno over here, dual monitor setup with a GTX660TI.

Edit:

As of today an `sudo apt update` and a `sudo apt upgrade` has resolved the issue on my end. Thanks elementary team :)

Comment: Why the downvote? I couldn't leave a comment on the original post because I don't have a rep yet, but thought I could still help by reporting I had the same issue.

Comment: Ok thankfully I'm not the only one, I'll try giving it another apt upgrade and hopefully it's resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem :(

Again, full screen on any browser (Firefox or Chrome) gets the image stuck, sound continues as normal.

Only solution is to move the fullscreen window to the laptop desktop, and then move the fullscreen video back to the widescreen monitor using keyboard shortcuts. That seems to work. The source of the video doesn't seem to matter (youtube, or other).

Haven't had that problem with the previous version of Elementary, only with Juno; and no, `apt-get upgrade` hasn't helped.